# Errow while installing SCVMM 2012 R2

Tags: virtual-machine, virtualization, sccm

When i'm trying to install VMM on server 2012 R2, I get the following error
"Installing G:\amd64\setup\msi\Server\vmmServer.msi failed with Windows Installer error 1603.
See C:\ProgramData\VMMLogs\vmmServer.log for more information. After resolving the problem, retry setup."

can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem in my environment.

Here are the steps how i did solve this issue

Since VMM 2012 R2 Requires ADK 8.1 and this requires SQL 2012 Express.

In order SQL Server 2012 to be installed successfully .Net Frame Work 3.5 feature on Windows Server has to be enabled first, in this case it is not not being installed by ADK Installation wizard as a result SQL service fails to start, which results on VMM installation to fail.

Please try to enable .Net Frame Work 3.5 feature on Windows Server 2012 R2 before you install ADK 8.1

Answer (score 0):

Look at the mentioned log file. If it mentions the error is produced by WebDeploy 3.5 then try uninstalling Microsoft Web Deploy and try again, that worked for me.